# Getting whole JSON input request in JavaCompute

Tags: json, websphere

I'm using IIB v10.0.0.18 and I have JSON input message which is received by http input node, and then a JavaCompute node in which I'm trying to get the whole JSON input.
I'm using below code to do this

```
MbMessage inMessage = inAssembly.getMessage();
MbElement inRoot = inMessage.getRootElement();
String inputMsg = inRoot.getFirstElementByPath("/JSON/Data/*").getValueAsString();
```

But this is resulting in the first line only of the input message.
I tried also

```
String inputMsg = inRoot.getFirstChild().getValueAsString();
```

And

```
String inputMsg = inRoot.getLastChild().getValueAsString();
```

But both are returning null.
Can anyone please tell me how to get the whole json input as a string in my JavaCompute.
My input JSON looks like this

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "A green door",
"price": 12.50
}
```

and I want this whole message to be retrieved from the JavaCompute node.

Update:
Based on Kimbert's answer, I updated the code to below and it worked:

```
MbMessage inMessage = inAssembly.getMessage();
MbElement inRoot = inMessage.getRootElement();
byte[] inRootBytes = inRoot.getLastChild().toBitstream(null, null, null, 0, 1208, 0);
String inRootString = new String(inRootBytes);
```

Now, inRootString has the string value of my input json.

Comment: I see you are using the single-parameter constructor String(byte[]). If you are converting a byte array into a string you should _always_ explicitly specify the encoding. Relying on default behaviour or 'it looks like it works' is sketchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MbElement class is just a wrapper for a 'syntax element' in the IIB message tree. So MbElement.getValueAsString will return the string value of the syntax element. That might be a string (if the MbElement represents a string field), or null, but it will never be the document fragment from which that element was parsed.

You need to use MbElement.toBitstream. If you use it on an MbElement that points to InputRoot.JSON then you should get the entire input bitstream.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kimbert, I used toBitstream and got the string value of my json input.
I updated the post with the solution in case someone needed it.
Thanks again for your help.